# Look up a number inside a list within a pandas cell, and return corresponding string value from a second DF

Tags: python, pandas

(I've edited the first column name in the labels_df for clarity)

I have two DataFrames, train_df and labels_df.  train_df has integers that map to attribute names in the labels_df.  I would like to look up each number within a given train_df cell and return in the adjacent cell, the corresponding attribute name from the labels_df.

[image]

I've tried variations of the function below but fear I am wayyy off:

```
def my_mapping(df1, df2):
    tags = df1['attribute_ids']
    for i in tags.iteritems():
        df1['new_col'] = df2.iloc[i]
    return df1
```

The data are originally from two csv files:

train.csv

[image]

labels.csv

[image]

I tried this from @Danny :

```
sample_train_df['attribute_ids'].apply(lambda x: [sample_labels_df[sample_labels_df['attribute_name'] == i]
                                              ['attribute_id_num'] for i in x])
```

*please note - I am running the above code on samples of each DF due to run times on the original DFs.
which returned:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created my own data.

train.csv

```
id,attrib
1,1 2 3
2,3 4 5
3,2 3 5
4,1 1 1
```

labels.csv

```
attrib_id,attrib_name
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
```

Read the csv files and create df1 and df2

After that use

```
def get_name(x):
    result = []
    for t in x.split(' '):
        result.append(df2[df2['attrib_id']==int(t)]['attrib_name'].values[0])
    return result

df1['attrib'] = df1['attrib'].apply(lambda x: get_name(x))
```

This will result in df1 looking like

[image] 
I guess you also doing the same thing when you referred @Danny. The only thing important here is to convert the **string into integer**